# How can I directly access inner class in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way I can access Swift inner classes from another class without the outer class

```
class Logic {

    class FranchiseLogic {
        
    }
}
```

I want to access `FranchiseLogic` without `Logic.FranchiseLogic`. Is this possible on Swift? In Java I import Logic class, something similar to that if possible

Comment: Do you mean you want to refer to `Logic.FranchiseLogic` from a third, unrelated class, with only its simple name - `FranchiseLogic`?

Comment: i think it's inheritance approach. so, it can be use with extend `Logic` class. can it be possible @Sweeper?

Comment: That's just the namespacing that's nested, there's no relation between `Logic` and `FranchiseLogic` whatsoever, so if you want to be able to refer to it directly, just declare it outside of `Logic`. There's no nested classes in Swift unlike in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a typealias

```
typealias FranchiseLogic = Logic.FranchiseLogic
```

This will allow you to use it as `FranchiseLogic` in the scope where the `typealias` is defined.